# iOS Disable Animation When Back Pressed

Tags: ios, swift3

When i press back button, the animation starts again and i loose buttons on my screen.

Here is a gif for better understanding:

https://i.gyazo.com/9d2ec00152c614c94a2ab2c797e86e12.gif

```
eoverride func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    std.center.x += view.bounds.width
    prtl.center.x += view.bounds.width
    .
    .

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.std.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.6, options: [], animations: {
        self.prtl.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
    .
    .
}
```

How can i stop animation start again to prevent loosing buttons on the screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    std.center.x += view.bounds.width
    prtl.center.x += view.bounds.width
    .
    .
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.std.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.6, options: [], animations: {
        self.prtl.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Remove code from viewWillAppear and try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate view only the first time when your view load then you need to call your code inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
//MARK: - Life cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    std.center.x += view.bounds.width
    prtl.center.x += view.bounds.width

    // Call your animation related code here
    animateView()
}

func animateView(){
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
         self.std.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
     }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.6, options: [], animations: {
        self.prtl.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
     }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
        self.std.center.x = 0
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.6, options: [], animations: {
        self.prtl.center.x = 0
    }, completion: nil)
    .
    .
}
```

Or use a BOOL to check

```
let shouldAnimate = (self.prtl.center.x != 0)

if shouldAnimate ....
```